# How to determine parameters for t-SNE for reducing dimensions?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, word2vec, word-embeddings, tsne

I am very new to word embeddings. I want to visualize how the documents are looking after learning. I read that t-SNE is the approach to do it. I have 100K documents with 250 dimensions as size of the embedding. There are several packages available as well.

However, for t-SNE, I don't know how many iterations or the value of alpha or the value of perpexility I should keep to learn better.

Are these hyper-parameters or can these be determined by some attributes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I highly reccomend the article [How to Use t-SNE Effectively](http://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/). It has great animated plots of the tsne fitting process, and was the first source that actually gave me an intuitive understanding of what tsne does.

At a high level, perplexity is the parameter that matters.  It's a good idea to try perplexity of 5, 30, and 50, and look at the results.

But seriously, read How to Use t-SNE Effectively.  It will make your use of TSNE more effective.

For packages, use [Rtsne](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rtsne/index.html) in R, or [sklearn.manifold.TSNE](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) in python

Comment: For larger datasets and to use GPU in your computations. Check out the Rapids library by nVidia. [Rapids.AI](rapids.ai)

Answer (score 4):

I will cite the FAQ from [t-SNE website](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/). 
First for perplexity:

> How should I set the perplexity in t-SNE?
>
> The performance of t-SNE is fairly robust under different settings of
>   the perplexity. The most appropriate value depends on the density of
>   your data. Loosely speaking, one could say that a larger / denser
>   dataset requires a larger perplexity. Typical values for the
>   perplexity range between 5 and 50.

For all other paremeters I would consider reading this:

> How can I asses the quality of the visualizations that t-SNE
>   constructed?
>
> Preferably, just look at them! Notice that t-SNE does not retain
>   distances but probabilities, so measuring some error between the
>   Euclidean distances in high-D and low-D is useless. However, if you
>   use the same data and perplexity, you can compare the Kullback-Leibler
>   divergences that t-SNE reports. It is perfectly fine to run t-SNE ten
>   times, and select the solution with the lowest KL divergence.

In other words it means: look at the plot, if the visualization is good don't change the parameters. You can also choose the run with the lowest KL divergence for each fixed perplexity.